# listview in the checkbox with image

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

```
 SizedBox(
          height: 300,
          child: ListView.separated(
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                return Row(
                  children: [
                    Transform.scale(
                      scale: 0.30.h,
                      child: Checkbox(
                        activeColor: Colors.grey.shade400,
                        checkColor: Colors.transparent,
                        value: true,
                        onChanged: (deger) {},
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 80,
                      child: Image.asset(
                        "assets/images/apple.jpg",
                        fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                );
              },
              separatorBuilder: (_, index) {
                return const Divider();
              },
              itemCount: 3),
        )
```

I want it to be proportioned and come side by side exactly like this, but it doesn't, can you help? and i want to be work for web same time.pls send me code.

Comment: can you add a screenshot how it currently looks?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this code

```dart
class ListFVC extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListFVC({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ListFVC> createState() => _ListFVCState();
}

class _ListFVCState extends State<ListFVC> {
  //you might include item itself
  List<int> _selectedIndex = [];

  void updateSelectedItems(int index) {
    if (_selectedIndex.contains(index)) {
      _selectedIndex.remove(index);
    } else {
      _selectedIndex.add(index);
    }

    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          return ListView.separated(
            itemCount: 44,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return SizedBox(
                height: constraints.maxHeight * .2,
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    updateSelectedItems(index);
                  },
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Checkbox(
                        value: _selectedIndex.contains(index),
                        onChanged: (v) {
                          // updateSelectedItems(index); // parent inkwell will handle this
                        },
                      ),

                      // you can provide fixed size for image
                      Image.asset(
                        "assets/images/image01.png",
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 10,
                      ) // you can use padding instead
                      ,
                      Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text("sub mid item $index "),
                            Text("sub mid item "),
                            Spacer(),
                            Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                                child: Text("bottom Item ")),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text("sub mid item $index "),
                            Text("sub mid item "),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            separatorBuilder: (c, i) => const Divider(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```